# Class loading by bootstrapclassloader

Tags: java, classloader

Here is what I was asked in interview:

> If a new method is added to String class and compiled and put in
>   rt.jar, then will bootstrap class loader load it?
>
> I answered that it will not get loaded but could not tell why.

Please help me with correct answer and explanation of that.

Comment: Why should it not be loaded? Why do *you* think it won't be loaded?

Comment: How should we explain *your* claims?

Comment: If it gets loaded then you can do anything inside that method and that will violate the security of JVM. And it's not about String, its about any class loaded by bootstrap classloader.

Comment: @Holger, No need to explain my claim. I just need your perspective about the correct answer of this question.

Comment: @AKS: if you can *modify* `rt.jar`, then damn right, you can violate the security (and everything else) about the JVM.

Comment: @AKS: No, you didn’t ask for the correct answer. You asked “Please help me in understanding *why it will not get loaded*”. So your question contains a claim. Your claim.

Comment: @Holger, Thanks! going to update that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be loaded.

And not just that: it need not even be in `rt.jar`, if you prepend a jar file to the boot-classpath (see [`-Xbootclasspath/p:path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BGBGEDBG)), then you can even load `java.lang.*` classes from other jar files.

This *of course* is a way to violate the security of the JVM, but you need pretty deep access (either write-access to `rt.jar` or access to the command line parameters of the JVM) and when you have those, you can do a lot more than just replace `String.toString()`.

Comment: Ok, so what i can understand from here is that getting write access to rt.jar itself is first security violation, and class loader will load anything in rt.jar. And for any application, from outside, you can't get String class loaded by Bootstrap class loader as it will load from rt.jar.